# JwtSecurityTokenHandler and TokenValidationParameters

Tags: c#, validation, security, jwt, identity

I used to have a reference to `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.JWT` and everything was working fine.

I updated to use the new `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` but nothing seems to work now. It cannot find the `ValidateToken` method of the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` and the `TokenValidationParameters` have no `AllowedAudience`, `SigningToken` or `ValidateExpiration` properties.

What am I missing here? Can anyone provide with a working sample of a JWT validation with this?

My "old" code :

```
private static void ValidateJwt(string jwt)
{
    var handler = new JWTSecurityTokenHandler();
    var validationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.JWT.TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        AllowedAudience = "https://my-rp.com",
        //SigningToken = new BinarySecretSecurityToken(Convert.FromBase64String(myBase64Key)),
        SigningToken = new X509SecurityToken(
           X509
           .LocalMachine
           .My
           .Thumbprint
           .Find("UYTUYTVV99999999999YTYYTYTY88888888", false)
           .First()),
        ValidIssuer = "https://my-issuer.com/trust/issuer",
        ValidateExpiration = true
    };

    try
    {
        var principal = handler.ValidateToken(jwt, validationParameters);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("{0}\n {1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

After a lot of research and tests, I finally found that some properties names for `TokenValidationParameters` had changed and `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken()` method signature too.

So here's the modified working version of the above code.

```
private static void ValidateJwt(string jwt)
{
    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();   
    var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidAudience = "https://my-rp.com",
        IssuerSigningTokens = new List<X509SecurityToken>() { new X509SecurityToken(
           X509
           .LocalMachine
           .My
           .Thumbprint
           .Find("UYTUYTVV99999999999YTYYTYTY88888888", false)
           .First()) },
        ValidIssuer = "https://my-issuer.com/trust/issuer",
        CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.None,
        RequireExpirationTime = true
    };

    try
    {
        SecurityToken validatedToken;
        var principal = handler.ValidateToken(jwt, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("{0}\n {1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

And for the reference, the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` lives in the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens` namespace. Don't forget to add the package "[JSON Web Token Handler For the Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/)" (version 4.0.0 at the time I write theses lines).

Hope it can save a few hours of search for some of you guys!

Comment: Thanks for this! Ugh, so frustrating :\ Coding in ASP.NET has been an absolute nightmare compared to other frameworks out there

Comment: @ossys Perhaps it's just the Azure part? Been using ASP.NET for a while and love it. Gotta do the Azure AD stuff now and it's a pain in the rear.

Comment: @Shelby115 glad you are having better luck with ASP.NET! :) I think for RESTful development Node.js supports JSON formats natively, so it is tough trying to manage C# objects and mappings... but for this JWT problem it was a change to the API that had no documentation I could find on it :(

Comment: The `RequireExpirationTime` is set to `true` in the default constructor for `TokenValidationParameters`.

Comment: @ossys .NET documentation has gone downhill. I am finding it difficult to find any information on these classes.   Too much trial and error.