# Removing "issuer" from JWT results in 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt, access-token

I am using the *Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Tokens* package to implement JWT tokens in ASP.NET. I want to remove the field **issuer** from my tokens, by using the following configuration:

```
new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
    AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
    {
        new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, audienceSecret)
    },
    TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters() { ValidateIssuer = false }
}
```

I then generate JWT tokens without the issuer:

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer:null, audience:audienceId, signingCredentials: signingKey);
```

However, after adding the **TokenValidationParameters** and removing the issuer field, I receive the error **401 Unauthorized**. The validation works perfectly fine if I keep the issuer in the JWT.

Am I allowed to remove the issuer from the JWT? If not, what does the "ValidateIssuer" parameter do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though issuer is optional according to JWT standards, the *System.Identitymodel.Tokens.Jwt* package v.4.x apparently still requires it. The problem should be resolved in since *System.Identitymodel.Tokens.Jwt* has been updated to v.5. However, this version of the package does not seem to be compatible with Microsoft Owin.

Answer (score 1):

The field `iss` is a [standard field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token#Standard_fields) in JWT, but according to the specification [it is optional](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html#rfc.section.4.1.1):

> The iss (issuer) claim identifies the principal that issued the JWT. The processing of this claim is generally application specific. The iss value is a case-sensitive string containing a StringOrURI value. Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

Nevertheless, as the `iss` field represents the identity provider that issued the token, it is often required by libraries to be able to verify the source of the token. I *guess* this is why you can not remove it without breaking things.

Just from looking at the specification, you should be able to remove it nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Issuer is optional

Issuer claim represents the Authorization server (Token Issuer) party.(i.e. It was be path of your application URL who will generate token it can be http://localhost:4496/webapi or www.domainexample.com).

Best way to implement TokenValidationParameters, here is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693798/jwtsecuritytokenhandler-and-tokenvalidationparameters)

Please go through this [link](http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/),  It will be helpful

Hope I have clear your point. If not then can throw again :)