# Validating JWT against AAD

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I have a web API that will receive a JWT token and I just need to validate the token against Azure. AAD already has my API registered. I'm using the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` library, can someone confirm whether this is how to validate the token? There's a separate application that has oauth2 implemented and gets the JWT token from AAD, it passes it to my API.

```
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace Shared.Service.Helpers
{
    public static class JwtValidator
    {
        static public async Task<bool> ValidateToken(string token, TokenValidationParameters tvp)
        {
            try
            {
                var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var result = await handler.ValidateTokenAsync(token, tvp);
                return result.IsValid;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also what exactly do I need to pass in for the `TokenValidationParameters` parameter? Are there any required fields that I need to fill in or can I just pass the JWT token with a generic declared `TokenValidationParameters` object without initializing any fields?

Comment: Well depending on what you want to achieve, you should initialize the TokenValidationParameter. Especially regarding the issue etc. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693798/jwtsecuritytokenhandler-and-tokenvalidationparameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ValidateTokenAsync` does not "validate against azure" (does not send it anywhere), it validates the token on your computer in memory, i.e. checks that the token fields match what you expect to see in them. It is basically nothing more than a field comparison.

With "token validation parameters" you just pass which token fields you want to check. For example, if you want to make sure that the issuer of the token is someone you expect, you pass the issuer, and it will be compared with "issuer" field that is contained in the token. The same applies to the "audience". If you want the token to be used only for a specific audience, you pass that parameter in the validation parameters. Also, you can check that the token is not expired, for example, and that it is properly signed. Stuff like that.

Important note: you should only validate tokens that are intended for your application. You should not validate Microsoft's tokens (such as graph tokens or office tokens for example). If you try to validate those manually, you may get a validation error (invalid signature), this is expected.

Comment: You can decode your token to see what's inside using websites like https://jwt.ms/ or https://jwt.io To figure out the issuer, etc - what to check. Basic check is signature of course and the expiration date

Comment: Please note that a common practice is not to use somebody else's token but instead exchange it to a token intended for your application using on-behalf-of call: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow

Comment: Means, if a client calls Service X and then wants to reuse the token it gets for ServiceX to call ServiceY instead (i.e. your service), it should get a new token (for your service), i.e. exchange X token to Y token using Azure call. It is not a good idea to call ServiceY directly using a token intended for ServiceX.